# JSON object appending only last records using Java

Tags: java, json

I'm iterating a list object and creating a JSON object using Java. My list has two records, but its appending only last record. Here is my code

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();       
    try (Session session = factory.openSession()) {
        String hql = "FROM Personalisation E WHERE E.userId = "+id;
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        List<?> results = query.list();     
        for(int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
            Persona p = (Person) results.get(i);
            System.out.println(p.getCourseId());
            obj.put("courseId", p.getCourseId());
            obj.put("CourseValue", (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(p.getCourseValue()));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Result is

```
C5 <-- Course ID
C6 <-- Course ID
{"CourseValue":{"color":"blue","value":"#f00"},"courseId":"C6"}
```

There should be one more record.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Json objects are more like maps so you always overwrite previous records. Use json arrays instead (most libraries have classes like `JSONArray`) and create a new json object for each record.

Comment: @Thomas, Can you plz give me a reference or update the code?

Comment: I assume you're already using some sort of Json library so have a look at it's docs.

Comment: I'm using JSONArray of org.json.simple package.

Comment: Ok, then just create the array before the loop and the object inside and call `array.add(obj)` at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your update Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store your `JsonObject` instances in an array, I used gson as example, because you haven't specified the framework to be used:

```
JsonArray array = new JsonArray();

try (Session session = factory.openSession()) {
    String hql = "FROM Personalisation E WHERE E.userId = "+id;
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    List<?> results = query.list();

    for(int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

        Persona p = (Person) results.get(i);
        System.out.println(p.getCourseId());
        obj.put("courseId", p.getCourseId());
        obj.put("CourseValue", (JSONObject) new  JSONParser().parse(p.getCourseValue()));

        array.add(obj);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return array;
```